# ActionBarSherlock - Tab Text ellipsize on <Android 3.0 devices

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to change the tab text of the ActionBarSherlock ActionBar tabs on < Android 3.0 devices.

On devices > Android 3.0 the text simply get wrapped in two lines. On devices < Android 3.0 the text is single line and seems to be set to ellipsize: marquee and marqueeRepeatLimit: marquee_forever.

I'm trying to change this on < Android 3.0 devices to also make the text two lines.

Here is what is try to do:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabTextStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:lines">2</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#f00</item>
</style>
```

The `textColor`attribute is there to make sure that I am even doing the correct thing at all. And yes I am, the tab text is red.

But unfortunately the ellipsize setting doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any ideas on how to change this?

Answer (score 2):

Although you probably don't need this anymore (considering the question is more than a year old), there might be someone landing here through a google search and might find this answer useful.

Changing the style to this will make it work:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabTextStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:lines">2</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#f00</item>
</style>
```

`android:actionBarTabTextStyle` represents the TextStyle of the default `ActionBar` for HC+ and `actionBarTabTextStyle` the TextStyle for `ActionBarSherlock`.